# SQL CE фильтр по количеству уникальным значениям + название значения

Tags: sql

Мне нужна запись в SQL CE чегото вроде этого(не уверен что правильно):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT host) AS hostCounter, host
FROM [Requests]
ORDER BY hostCounter DESC
```

Если иметь ввиду что в SQL CE не раобтает COUNT(DISTINCT host)

фактически должно выйти чтото вроде

40 gooogle.com

20 vk.com

10 durka.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS hostCounter, host
FROM [Requests]
group by host
ORDER BY hostCounter DESC
```

Comment: как ведь все просто оказалось. Спасибо!